# Running application using sbt run and some flags

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am currently running a akka application with the below command after I run

```
sbt assembly

java -Dconfig.resource=/application.test.conf -cp /path/to/folder:./target/scala-2.11/app-name.jar ca.path.to.main
```

**Is there a way I can pass this information using sbt and some flags** so I don't have to run the `sbt assembly` task everytime just to run the application?

```
sbt run config=/application.test.conf cp=/path/to/folder:
```

(something like the above)

Answer (score 0):

Options that are passed to JVM are read by sbt from the `javaOptions` setting. So you can configure this setting to have the options you want and then tell sbt to fork new JVM process everytime you run your app from sbt so these options are applied. You can do this from sbt console:

```
set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/application.test.conf"
set fork := true
run
```

Or in your `build.sbt` file:

```
javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=/application.test.conf"
fork := true
```

However this might not be the most idiomatic approach to reach your underlying end goal.

Comment: I want to be able to change /application.test.conf to /application.env2.conf  etc.  i.e I dont' want that to be fixed, I want to be able to have many environments.